# Python: error IOError: [Errno2] bad interpretation of file or directory

Tags: python, file, directory

I'm try trying to read an csv file and the interpreter return a bad directory by duplicating the \

```
> result = [[urlparse(u).netloc] for u in file ('S:\Dev\Python\BDDtest.csv')]

>>IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S:\\\Dev\\\Python\\\BDDtest.csv'
```

When I put it in a `ufile ='S:\Dev\Python\BDDtest.csv'` and print it the result is correctly interpreted

but when I try a

```
> result = [[urlparse(u).netloc] for u in file (ufile)]
```

It return the same error...

Anyone as a fix or an explaination

Comment: Yes exactly I haven't the same error at home beacuse I use it in a Linux shell

Comment: you are opening the file `S:\Dev\Python\BDDtest.csv` in a Linux shell?

Comment: > r'S:\Dev\Python\BDDtest.csv' same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a hack with os.path.abspath will help?

```
import os
result = [[urlparse(u).netloc] for u in 
          file(os.path.abspath('S:\Dev\Python\BDDtest.csv'))]
```

You can also try using ntpath explicitly:

```
import ntpath
result = [[urlparse(u).netloc] for u in 
          file(ntpath.abspath('S:\Dev\Python\BDDtest.csv'))]
```

Comment: elegant way to reverse but I think that changing the \ to / is sufficient for the moment,BTW I keep it in mind thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try replace `\` to `/`

Comment: It works I imagine it's because switch from Linux to MS the structure of direction from C:\ to C:/ why in this case the properties files gives the contrary such as C:\?